# Pandas append rows to dataframe with two indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really having a hard time diving into pandas:

here I would like to establish a DataFrame of this kind with a double index: i1 and i2:

```
cols = ["i1", "i2", "d1", "d2", "d3"]
T = pd.DataFrame( columns=cols ).set_index(["i1", "i2"])
```

and then append rows to that with the index in the right spot

so far I've tried:

```
T.loc[ 1,2 ] = pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30})
```

and also:

```
T.append( pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30}, name=(1,2)) )
```

none of which gives the desired result.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Your second option works for me (with 0.16.2).

Comment: You should check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) and in particular why you need the syntax in Joris' answer `T.loc[( 1,2),: ]` to disambiguate your intention, to some extent calling `(axis=0)` is another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first attempt the following works:

```
In [258]:
T.loc(axis=0)[ (1,2) ] = pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30})
T

Out[258]:
       d1  d2  d3
i1 i2            
1  2   10  20  30
```

This `T.append( pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30}, name=(1,2)) )` also works fine in pandas `0.16.2`

Comment: the append does not change my T in my 0.16.1 version

Comment: I suggest upgrading if you can

Answer (score 1):

The first option works if you do `T.loc[(1,2),:]` instead of `T.loc[ 1,2 ]` (so pandas knows the two values are both for the row index (for the two row index levels):

```
In [63]: T = pd.DataFrame( columns=cols ).set_index(["i1", "i2"])

In [64]: T.loc[( 1,2),: ] = pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30})

In [65]: T
Out[65]:
       d1  d2  d3
i1 i2
1  2   10  20  30
```

A more extensive explanation: `T.loc[ 1,2 ]` will try to access row 1 and column 2. Therefore you need to pass `(1,2)` as a tuple and explicitely select all columns with `:`, giving `.loc[(1,2),:]`.

The second just works for me (with pandas 0.16.2):

```
In [68]: T = pd.DataFrame( columns=cols ).set_index(["i1", "i2"])

In [69]: T.append( pd.Series({"d1":10, "d2":20, "d3":30}, name=(1,2)) )
Out[69]:
       d1  d2  d3
i1 i2
1  2   10  20  30
```

But, be aware that appending values in both these ways will always take a copy of the existing frame.
It may be better to rethink your approach and make the dataframe with the data at once (but of course, this depends on your application).